# Compute the inverse Laplace transform of $\mathrm{e}^{\left( i- 1\right)\sqrt{ms/h}\ x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

- I'm trying to solve the Schrödinger's equations using the method of Laplace transforms, but I can't figure out the inverse transform once I've reached this point.
- I'm a high school student, so I'm self-taught and I haven't much experience with the theory behind the Inverse Laplace transform.
- I'm sorry for the bad typing of my formulas but this is my first post.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$
Basically, you want to compute
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\!
\expo{\alpha x\!\root{s}}\!\!\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\right\vert_{\ t\ >\ 0}}}$
where
$\ds{\alpha \equiv \pars{\ic - 1}\root{m \over h} \mbox{is a}\ constant}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\!
\expo{\alpha x\!\root{s}}\!\!\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\right\vert_{\ t\ >\ 0}}\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{-\infty}^{0}\expo{\alpha x\root{-s}\ic}\expo{ts}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} -
\int_{0}^{-\infty}\expo{\alpha x\root{-s}\pars{-\ic}}\expo{ts}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\alpha x\root{s}\ic}\expo{-ts}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\alpha x\root{s}\pars{-\ic}}\expo{-ts}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{\alpha x\root{s}}
\expo{-ts}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] = &\ \stackrel{s\ \mapsto\ s^{2}}{=}\,\,\,
-\,{2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}s\sin\pars{\alpha xs}
\expo{-ts^{2}}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-\,{\alpha \over 2\root{\pi}}
\,{x\exp\pars{-\alpha^{2}x^{2}/\bracks{4t}} \over t^{3/2}}\,,\qquad \Re\pars{x} > 0} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help. Just to be sure, is a=(i-1)sqrt(m/h)?

Comment: I'm also worried about what happens to the t variable: at the beginning I have a function of position and time, f(x,t), then I use the Laplace transform to obtain a new function H(x,s). Shouldn't I expect to obtain another function of x and t after applying the inverse transform?

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera Yes, $\alpha$ is the one you wrote in your comment. I didn’t see any time $t$ in your question. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer. As far as the time-dependency is concerned, I'll explain "my" method to solve the problem from which I derived the function stated at the beginning of  my question. To solve the Schrodinger's equation, I apply the Laplace transform to both sides of my equation. So I start from a function f(x,t) and I obtain a new differential equation involving G(x,s). I solve the new equation and find the expression of G. Than, through the inverse Laplace transform, we should obtain another function F(x,t), which is time dependent

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera I just fixed it. I guess I misread your question. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera Might be worth mentioning that the Bromwich integral diverges for positive $m, h, x, t$.

Comment: I think I love you ahahaha. Thank you so much for your help!!